# Unable to add interactions to oculus handtracking in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I'm using the oculus integration package to implement hand tracking and have added the OVRCameraRig. Under the LeftHandAnchor I have added OVRCustomHandPrefab_L and similarly done the right hand. I have also enabled physics so the hands work and I can push items off the table in game.

However, I want to implement grabbing mechanism so I added the HandsManager prefab to the scene and put the above mentioned hand prefabs for the left and right hand fields. FInally, I added in the InteractableToolsSDKDriver but none of the interactable tools are working, the little blue dots aren't visible at all.

I'm not getting any error either. Please help, how should I fix this to get the Interactable tools to work?

Answer (score 0):

Well probably because you haven't add component "xr grab interactable" to the item that you wanna grab.

Comment: It would be better to add this kind of answer as a comment.

Comment: Thx dude I'll take care of it